# SKAction.runBlock -> missing argument for completion in call

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm quite new to Swift. I'm trying to run a block of animation code forever. What am I doing wrong here? It keeps complaining about "missing argument for completion in call".

[image]

```
func randomCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
    var temp = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10)))/10
    println(temp)
    return temp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not trying to run a block of code but simply run an action.

In your case you should be able to do like so :

```
let fadeAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaBy(self.randomCGFloat(), duration: 0.3)
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(fadeAction)

gameFieldMask.runAction(repeatAction)
```

Or in one line if you prefer :

```
gameFieldMask.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.fadeAlphaBy(self.randomCGFloat(), duration: 0.3)))
```